# Doubly exponential diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

Recently, i've been thinking of the diophantine equation:

$A^{B^C}+D^{E^F} = G^{H^I}$

Where, $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I \in [2, \infty)\cap \mathbb{N}$.

I discovered that one can construct a solution if one finds perfect powers $P, Q$ and a positive integer $n$ that satisfies $nP +1 = Q$. It is not hard to see that a solution to the diophantine equation follows from such $P, Q, n$.

$$(2^n)^P + (2^n)^P=2^Q$$

I call these the trivial solutions. My question is, are there any non-trivial solution to this diophantine equation?

Comment: $256^{3^2}+512^{2^3}=2^{73}$, but that's trivial too (in a way). Other than that, it is too complicated to investigate.

Comment: See the introduction [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/S.Siksek/papers/bealconj.pdf).

Comment: @IvanNeretin $G^{H^I}=2^{73^1}$ in your example, but we need $I\ge 2$.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I was misled by the OP's own example.

Comment: Then have this: $$512^{2^5}+4294967296^{3^2}=2^{17^2}$$

Comment: @IvanNeretin   Even that is a trivial solution.

Comment: Agreed. This is what I should have put as an example in my first comment, with the rest of it going verbatim as it is.